# What is the etymology of какаовелла?

Tags: этимология

Inspired by [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/65220/48351), what is the etymology of [какаовелла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0)? The какао part is easy, but what about велла?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149517/discussion-on-question-by-rodrigo-de-azevedo-what-is-the-etymology-of-); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: In Italian, `caccavelle` is a kind of pasta and its etymology is not actually connected to the word cacao.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, the bean - the seed of the cacao tree *Theobroma cacao* - is separated into the inner "nib" - used to make chocolate - and the fibrous outer protective layer
called the "shell" or "vella" or "husk" - used for mulch/fertilizer or teas/infusions.

Here's an example web page using the term "vella": https://www.ec21.com/product-details/Cocoa-Bean-Husk-Shell-Vella--11274898.html

[image]

Transcription:

> We have cocoa bean shell/vella/husk from our facility for export. Low fat and high fat cocoa husk is available on request. Products are well dried and meet with international standards. We have the capacity to load 300 tons monthly and our average loading capacity is 28 tons in 40 ft HC. Contact us today for videos and pictures of our facility and product.

It comes from Latin "villus" hair, tuft of hair, shaggy hair.

Compare Spanish "vello" body hair, facial fuzz, bloom on the skin of a fruit.

Not Latin "vela" - plural of "velum" sail, curtain, covering, and "velare" to cover, to veil - that became "veil".

Comment: very nice finding!

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that the Latin *vellus* is related to the Russian волос.  Allegedly, the common Proto-Indo-European root is [h₂welh₁-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h₂welh₁-)